# como realizar un v-for con condicional en vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo esa duda, el tema esta en que la documentación de VUE, no recomienda utilizar v-for y un v-if al mismo tiempo, recomienda que se utilice un metodo dentro de la propiedad "computed". El problema esta que los metodos que estan dentro de computed no son reactivos asi que no me funciona:

Aca les muestro un pequeño ejemplo de lo que digo:

```
<template>
 <div>
     <ul v-for="(user,index) in users" :key="user.id">
          <li>{{user.name}}
                 <button @click="hide(index)">Esconder</button>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

```
  <script>
  export default {
   props: {
    usuarios: Array
  },
    data (){
        return{
           usuarios:[
                  {id:1, nombre:"pepe",show:true},
                  {id:2, nombre:"kokun",show:true},
                  {id:3, nombre:"pepon",show:true},
                  {id:4, nombre:"pepona",show:true}
                  ],
          users: []
           }
   },
    methods:{
         hide(i){
              this.users[i]= {...this.users[i],show:false};
           }
      }
    computed: {
        return this.users= _.pickBy(this.usuarios,(a)=>{
                  return a.show;
                   })
   }
 }
 </script>
```

De esa lista que esta ahi solo tengo que mostrar dinamicamente los que son activos, usando _.pickBy(), si muestra los usuarios que en este caso estan activos, pero yo al mismo tiempo tengo un boton que al darle click cambio el estado de la variable show a falso, por lo que teoricamente no se tendria que ver.

Comment: observación: `users` y `usuarios`

Comment: No entiendo lo que dices.

Comment: Lee todo tu código detenidamente. Observación 2: falta coma en los objetos javascript dentro del arreglo `usuarios`

Comment: Entonces @fredyfx en este caso se le recomiendan las correcciones antes que cerrarla no?

Comment: Sucede que ese `_.pickBy` es de Lodash. Para reproducir una pregunta, la persona que publica debería al menos mencionar todo lo referente, le hace la vida más simple a quienes desees colaborar con la respuesta :D

Comment: Listo, ya quedo arreglado..pero aun no entiendo como resolver esto

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar qué hace esta línea `this.users[i]= {...this.users[i],show:false};` ?

Comment: selecciono el item por medio de su key (this.users[i]). Luego le re asigno todos los items que compone ese this.users (por medio del spread operator '...') y le reemplazo el show:true por show:false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, me parece extraña la manera en la que utilizas computed. No soy un experto en Vue, pero creo que se tendría que quitar la propiedad users de *data* y declararlo como propiedad en *computed*:

```
...
    computed: {
        users: function(){
            return _.pickBy(this.usuarios,(a)=>{ return a.show;});
        }
    }
...
```

En cuanto al principal problema, es precisamente la reactividad de los objetos en users.

La solución completa sería la siguiente:

```
<ul v-for="(user,index) in users" v-bind:key="user.id">
    <li>{{user.nombre}}
        <button @click="hide(user)">Esconder</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Aquí itero utilizando la propiedad users de *computed* y paso el objeto user a la función *hide* cuando se realiza el click sobre el botón.

```
export default {
            props: {
                usuarios: Array
            },
            data (){
                return{
                    usuarios:[
                        {id:1, nombre:"pepe",show:true},
                        {id:2, nombre:"kokun",show:true},
                        {id:3, nombre:"pepon",show:true},
                        {id:4, nombre:"pepona",show:true}
                    ]
                }
            },
            methods:{
                hide(user){
                    // Simplemente se cambia a false su propiedad show
                    user.show = false;
                }
            },
            computed:{
                users: function(){
                    // Se obtienen los usuarios activos
                    var usuariosActivos = this.usuarios.filter((v)=>{return v.show; });
                    return usuariosActivos;
                }
            }
        }
```

Finalmente, en el método *hide* solamente se cambia la propiedad *show* del usuario a false y eso mantendrá la reactividad. Vale la pena mencionar que esto es posible gracias al v-bind:key que se utiliza después de v-for.

En computed solamente me dí la libertad de sustituir lodash y utilizar vanilla js.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.